# Python OOP: create an object that is an instance of multiple classes

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

Say I built some classes containing some instance methods:

```
class A:
    def func_of_A(self):
        print("foo")

class B:
    def func_of_B(self):
        print("bar")
```

**How can I construct an object/variable `c` that is an instance of both `A` and `B`**, so that I can call both `c.func_of_A()` and `c.func_of_B()`?

I could of course build a new class inheriting from `A` and `B` and make `c` a member of that:

```
class C(A,B):
    pass

c = C()
```

But that is not what I am looking for. I would rather not create a new class every time I am planning to use a combination of already built ones.

I could also create a function to dynamically define a new class and return an instance of it:

```
def merge(*inherit_from):
    class D(*inherit_from):
        pass
    return D()

c = merge(A,B)
```

but this is beyond cursed, because now `merge(A,B)`, `merge(A)` and `merge(B)` all return the same type `<class '__main__.merge.<locals>.D'>`.

There should be an intended way to do this, shouldn't?

Is there a solution that scales well with the number of classes involved? If I already have `class A1`, `class A2`, ..., `class A100` and I want to construct some `c` to be an instance of `class A2, class A23, class A72, class A99` but not the others how would I do that? Creating a new class for every combination is pretty much impossible, given the ~2^100 combinations.

Comment: [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)…? But… is this really necessary? Why do you need such dynamic classes?

Comment: @deceze Exactly what I was looking for! I don't yet know the scope of my project or how many more features am I to add, so dynamic classes are a great help. I think it also helps with legibility. `type("C", (A,B), dict())` tells me exactly that I am working with an instance of `A` and `B`. If I *knew* for a fact that I will have exactly a hundred classes I would consider a better structure, not just some band-aid.

Comment: You create classes to have defined *types* that you can make some assertion about. The types you create should express some logical concept that your program works with. This helps you… *do stuff* in your code. If you declare a logical type `CustomerBillingSettings`, and that class implements methods relevant to… customer billing… then you can write code around that which does stuff with… customer billing. But if you're creating classes with useless names at runtime from unknown parents… what does that even mean and what are you going to do with those…?!

Comment: @deceze I'm making a GUI where I can easily drag and drop vertices and edges of graphs (graph as in mathematics) for presentation purposes. Kind of like GeoGebra. For flexibility I have a vertex class `class Vertex def clicked(): pass def draw(): pass` with some boilerplate empty methods, and then I define subclasses that extend these functions via `super()` calls. `class CanBeRemoved(Vertex) class Colored(Vertex) class CanBeHighlighted(Vertex) class AcceptsEdges(Vertex) class AcceptsMultiEdges(Vertex) class IsAnimated(Vertex)`. If I want to a vertex that has/lacks certain functionality (1/2)

Comment: or behaviour when I click on it or draw it on a canvas, then I can just create a `vertex = type(...)` which is instance of the appropriate subclasses. So when I click on the vertex I can just call `vertex.clicked()` all subclasses in the MRO call their respective `clicked()` method, and execute the respective logic. Saves me the trouble of setting up a million `bool` variables and convoluted `if` statements. Might be considered poor coding, but hey, it works. (2/2)

Comment: OK, I can see the utility in that. If your UI or other logic can somehow aggregate what attributes a node should have, you can generate such a node on the fly. You then just need to introspect each node for what capabilities it has and make it manipulable accordingly in the UI. I'd probably try to cache unique combinations of parent classes then, and not create a new type every time, even if that particular combination already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type()` for that as @deceze mentioned

```
>>> class A:
...     def a():
...         pass
... 
>>> class B:
...     def b():
...         pass
... 
>>> def merge(name: str, *parents):
...     return type(name, parents, dict())
... 
>>> C = merge("C", A, B)
>>> C.a()
>>> C.b()
>>>
```